# Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused in docker

Tags: docker, redis

I am using a redis-server:latest image. I used "docker run -it --name="redis2" redis:1 bash" command and got inside the container. I saw that by default redis is listening to Port: 6379.

```
Running in stand alone mode

Port: 6379

PID: 39

http://redis.io

[39] 01 Mar 09:03:45.669 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.4 [39] 01 Mar 09:03:45.669 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition.
```

To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect. [39] 01 Mar 09:03:45.669 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379

And then further there is no response. I tried "redis-cli ping". There was no response. Then I hit "ctrl+c" and type, "redis-cli ping" and get following response:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

I tried to change the port to 6001 by executing following:

```
redis-server --port 6003
```

And I see following response:

```
Running in stand alone mode

Port: 6003

PID: 47
```

And again I tried "redis-cli ping" and it threw me the same error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

How do I fix this? Also I have updated the port(the new port 6003) in "/etc/redis/redis.conf" location.

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Redis is listening on that port on the internal docker network, to access it from your local machine you need to map the container port to your local port using -p 6379:6379. That way if you have multiple redis containers you can map them each to different ports on your machine.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks a lot for the response. I tried following:  "docker run -it --name="redis3" -p 6000:6379 redis:1 bash" and I enter into container. I typed "redis-cli" and it threw me error : Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused. I am sorry but I am little new to both docker and redis. Can you please let me know how can I make it run inside the container?

Comment: I got it. Ran "sudo service redis-server start" and it fixed the issue.

Comment: `6000:6379` this means that you're mapping port `6379` from inside the container to port `6000` on the host. That's why were not able to connect at `6379` the first time

Comment: I should do `docker run -p 6379:6379 redis`?

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's been a while but for anybody else faced the same issue; when you put the "sh" command in "docker run" it replaces the default command which is starting Redis server. 
So you can either spin up the container in a separate terminal like "docker run redis" and in another terminal run "docker exec -it #container_id sh"
which is a more common way to start up your container in a primary process and then attach a running shell to it or map the container port to your local port as Chris suggested.

Comment: Thank you for this. It just saved me hours of hair pulling

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting this error:

`Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused`

You may need to daemonize the redis-server so that docker can connect to it:

`/usr/local/bin/redis-server --daemonize yes`

Then try running `redis-cli ping` again.

Answer (score 1):

For future viewers:

1. run `sudo docker container ls` to get all running docker containers
2. `sudo docker exec -it <redis_container_name> redis-cli -h <ec2_ip_address> -p 6379:6379 FLUSHALL`

Hope this helped you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem tonight.

I was using a Redis container created from my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
redis:
    container_name: 'myproject-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

My solution was to use the container "ID" -> here 'redis' instead of using the normal connection IP `127.0.0.1`.

Why ? I assume that my Docker was creating a bridge directly to the created container (like it's often the case for MySQL i.e.).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using redis@4.4.0, when passing the host and port I got the same connection error message in nodejs. Using a lower version (3.1.2) worked for me. Additionally, I have read in the documentation that redis@4.4.0 accepts a connection url.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33083730)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a laravel docker project. I had to change the REDIS_HOST variable in the .env.

Before:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

After:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
```